# Conditionally using .reverse in the same line with Scala

Tags: scala, combinators

I have a composition of combinators in Scala, and the last one is `.top`, which I could use as `.top(num)(Ordering[(Int, Int)].reverse)` depending on a boolean parameter.

How do I implement this composition of combinators to use or not use `.reverse` depending on the boolean parameter, in the same line? I mean, without creating another `val` to indicate whether `.reverse` is used?

```
val mostPopularHero = sparkContext
  .textFile("resource/marvel/Marvel-graph.txt") // build up superhero co-apperance data
  .map(countCoOccurrences) // convert to (hero ID, number of connections) RDD
  .reduceByKey((x, y) => x + y) // combine entries that span more than one line
  .map(x => (x._2, x._1)) // flip it from (hero ID, number of connections) to (number of connections, hero ID)
  .top(num)(Ordering[(Int, Int)].reverse)
```

Comment: What is the boolean parameter you are referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 0**

As *nicodp* has already pointed out, if you have a boolean variable `b` in scope, you can simply replace the expression

```
Ordering[(Int, Int)]
```

by an `if`-expression

```
if (b) Ordering[(Int, Int)] else Ordering[(Int, Int)].reverse
```

I have to admit that this is the shortest and clearest solution I could come up with.

However... I didn't quite like that the expression `Ordering[(Int, Int)]` appears in the code *twice*. It doesn't really matter in this case, because it's short, but what if the expression were a bit longer? Apparently, even [Ruby has something for such cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48585778/chaining-function-calls-in-scala-or-equiavelent-of-rubys-yield-self).

So, I tried to come up with some ways to *not repeat* the subexpression `Ordering[(Int, Int)]`. The nicest solution would be if we had a default `Id`-monad implementation in the standard library, because then we could simply wrap the one value in `pure`, and then `map` it using the boolean.
But there is no `Id` in standard library. So, here are a few other proposals, just for the case that the expression in question becomes longer:

**Solution 1**

You can use blocks as expressions in scala, so you can replace the above
`Ordering[(Int, Int)]` by:

```
{val x = Ordering[(Int, Int)]; if (b) x else x.reverse}
```

*Update: Wait! This is shorter than the version with repetition! ;)*

**Solution 2**

Define the function that conditionally reverses an ordering, declare `Ordering[(Int, Int)]` as the type of the argument, and then 
instead of re-typing `Ordering[(Int, Int)]` as an expression, use `implicitly`:

```
((x: Ordering[(Int, Int)]) => if (b) x else x.reverse)(implicitly)
```

**Solution 3**

We don't have `Id`, but we can abuse constructors and eliminators of other functors. For example, one could wrap the complex expression in a `List` or `Option`, then `map` it, then unpack the result. Here is a variant with `Some`:

```
Some(Ordering[(Int, Int)]).map{ x => if(b) x else x.reverse }.get
```

Ideally, this would have been `Id` instead of `Some`. Notice that Solution 1 does something similar with the default ambient monad.

**Solution 4**

Finally, if the above pattern occurs more than once in your code, it might be worth it to introduce some extra syntax to deal with it:

```
implicit class ReversableOrderingOps[X](ord: Ordering[X]) {
  def reversedIf(b: Boolean): Ordering[X] = if (b) ord.reverse else ord
}
```

Now you can define orderings like this:

```
val myConditionHolds = true
val myOrd = Ordering[(Int, Int)] reversedIf myConditionHolds
```

or use it in your lengthy expression directly:

```
val mostPopularHero = sparkContext
  .textFile("resource/marvel/Marvel-graph.txt")
  .map(countCoOccurrences)
  .reduceByKey((x, y) => x + y)
  .map(x => (x._2, x._1))
  .top(num)(Ordering[(Int, Int)] reversedIf myConditionHolds)
```

Comment: is not the continuation. It is another question. You solved my problem, thanks. I forgot to point your answer the best one. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if you have access to the boolean parameter here or not, but you can work this out as follows:

```
 .top(num)(if (booleanParameter) Ordering[(Int, Int)].reverse else Ordering[(Int, Int)])
```